# i changed my android app version and my app is running on android studio but when i generate apk and afte install it stop

Tags: android

> i changed my android app version and my app is running on android studio but when i generate apk and install it on ph then it unfortunately stop when open

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "anoop.example.com.rssreader"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6'
    // compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.6'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
compile 'com.github.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar:fadingactionbar:3.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

stack trace

> 05-27 21:35:07.854 1534-4425/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=anoop.example.com.rssreader/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10014 on display 0
>   05-27 21:35:08.080 4462-4472/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 257(20KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 36.607ms total 136.565ms
>   05-27 21:35:08.193 4462-4479/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   05-27 21:35:08.193 4462-4479/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb28bf760, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>   05-27 21:35:08.240 1862-2124/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa2b36e0
>   05-27 21:35:08.273 4462-4479/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   05-27 21:35:08.273 4462-4479/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xadc13f80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>   05-27 21:35:08.313 4462-4479/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa2b1760
>   05-27 21:35:08.396 1534-2064/? I/WindowManager: Switching to real app window: Window{d3469cd u0 anoop.example.com.rssreader/anoop.example.com.rssreader.MainActivity}
>   05-27 21:35:08.567 1534-1553/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed anoop.example.com.rssreader/.MainActivity: +681ms

Comment: What does "not working" exactly mean? Please be more specific, don't expect people to guess what your problem is.

Comment: not working mean ....when apk install and open it give unfortunately stop

Comment: Then please add the exception stack trace.

Comment: sir i m new here i dont know how to do it ..pls guide me

Answer (score 0):

The version code and name get overridden by values in your `build.gradle` file. So edit your `build.gradle` and rebuild.

Comment: sir can elleborate what are saying

Comment: try to reduce the javaMaxHeapSize. This may be the problem

Comment: sir i reduce tat but it was not worked ......if i reduce it more then it it gives value 2 error

Answer (score 0):

Put the same `versionName` as the `versionCode`. (Both version `2`) And don't forget to update your manifest also if you provided the version too:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.foo"
    android:versionName="2">
```

Comment: Without any stacktrace, we can't really pin point your issue... Maybe it has nothing to do with the version code

Comment: sir i posted stack trace of when i starting the app in abd it starts but when i generate apk and intall it in ph then it stops